Error: Could not find a production build in the './.next' directory on Azure Web Service when I upload Next.js website via Github actions
I am trying to upload a shell Next.js application onto Azure web services via github actions but get error.
"Error: Could not find a production build in the './.next' directory. Try building your app with 'next build' before starting the production server."
the folder structure of my artifact is
app

node_modules


package


server.js

and my startup command is node server.js
this is my yml file:
name: Build and deploy Node.js app to Azure Web App

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up Node.js version
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: '20.x'

      - name: npm install, build, and test
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run build
      
      - name: Copy static files
        run: |
          cp -R ./.next/static ./.next/standalone/.next/static

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: app
          path: .next/standalone

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: Production
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}
    
    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: app
      
      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v3
        with:
          app-name: 'frontend'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          package: .
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE }}

I have followed:
https://inmeta.medium.com/deploy-next-js-to-azure-3-effective-strategies-for-modern-developers-86a41c0f9d92 AND https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H4amPlNBTf0 examples of how to configure but am still having issues.
Does anyone know why this might be?

actions/upload-artifact@v4 no longer uploads hidden files and folders by default.
In order to fix your issue, you're going to need to add include-hidden-files: true to your workflow file like this:
 - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: app
          path: .next/standalone
          include-hidden-files: true

You can see the breaking changes included in @v4 here.
